# Publish Mappings fails with deserialisation error

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I am trying to create a Component Template which functions in [Retrofit mode](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-C0AD6DCC-ED65-441F-B361-928A18B2896D). When I add the `Publish Mappings` building block to the Component Template, attempting a render gives me the following message:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sdl.Web.Common.Models.Data.SummaryData]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Sure enough, the Output generated by the `Render Component Content` is a JSON object (thus, not an array) that looks like this:

```
{
    "Component":{<<Content here>>},
    "ComponentTemplate":{<<CT details here>>},
    "IsDynamic":true,
    "OrderOnPage":0
}
```

I've tried putting `Publish Mappings` at various locations in the pipeline, but it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to add the `Publish Mappings` TBB to your Component Template. The [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-C0AD6DCC-ED65-441F-B361-928A18B2896D) mentions:

> ... By invoking the `Publish Mappings` Template Building Block from the `Publish Setting` Template Building Block with its `retrofitMode` parameter set to `true`.

So all you need to do is leave your Component Template alone, and configure the retrofit mode, see also the [changes introduced in DXA 1.7](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-E6868924-E041-491F-8B8C-F017BC6B2F4E):

> To accommodate the existing Content Model, in the `Publish Settings` Template Building Block, found in the Folder `100 Master/Building Blocks/Framework/Developer/Templates/`, set the `retrofitMode` parameters of each of the `Publish Mappings` Template Building Blocks to true. This ensures that Schemas and Schema fields are mapped to unique identifiers on the DXA side.

I don't have a 1.7 system at hand, but I think the plural in the documentation is a typo, since I'm guessing there is only one `Publish Mappings` TBB in your `Publish Settings` TBB. As for changing the mentioned parameter, you can easily do it via the Template Builder, or use the following XML in the source tab (`tcm:1-2-2048` is a dummy TCM URI, use your own ;o):

```
<Template xlink:href="tcm:1-2-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Publish Mappings" />
<TemplateParameters>
  <Parameters xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/publishmappings">
    <retrofitMode xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/publishmappings">true</retrofitMode>
  </Parameters>
</TemplateParameters>
```

Comment: Thanks Bart. It's clear now. My problem was not the typo, but the fact that Publish Settings is described as a TBB. Once you know that you have to find a Component Template belonging to the framework, it's clear enough.

Comment: @DominicCronin good point, I see only now that it is indeed a Component Template and not a compound TBB, that is a more serious typo I'll report it. I also think the sentance "invoking the TBB" might be slightly misleading, I'll see what our tech writer can do to change that